# How to loop through and destroy all children of a game object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following script which is attached to a game object and run when I click a button in the editor:

```
public void ClearChildren() {
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
    float i = 0;
    foreach (Transform child in transform) {
        i += 1;
        DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
    }
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
}
```

It shows that the original `childCount` is 13 and the final value is 6. Furthermore, if I print out all `i` each iteration I see the values 0-6, showing that the loop only runs 7 times, not 13 as expected.

How can I delete all the children such that the final value is 0? For reference, the children I'm trying to delete were automatically created by a vendor script. I'm also running this script in `[ExecuteInEditMode]` for what it's worth.

The following script has the same behavior; if the `childCount` starts at 4 then it ends at 2:

```
public void ClearChildren() {
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
    for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; i++) {
        Transform child = transform.GetChild(i);
        DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
    }
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
}
```

If I try the following I get a runtime error pointing to the `foreach` line saying *"InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type."*

```
public void ClearChildren() {
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
    foreach ( GameObject child in transform) {
        DestroyImmediate(child);
    }
    Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
}
```

Comment: Check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/164600/foreach-loop-with-an-array-of-gameobjects.html) from Unity answers. It says _The instruction foreach loops through all elements in the group using internal pointers or indexes; you just supply a variable of the correct type, and foreach assigns to it a new element each iteration._

Comment: I don't really sure if its related to this issue, but try Debug.Log(child.gameObject.activeSelf); ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to remove the Object in the for loop while accessing them.

Here is what you should do:

1. Find all Child objects and store them in an array
2. Destroy them in another loop

   ```
    public void ClearChildren()
    {
        Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
        int i = 0;

        //Array to hold all child obj
        GameObject[] allChildren = new GameObject[transform.childCount];

        //Find all child obj and store to that array
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            allChildren[i] = child.gameObject;
            i += 1;
        }

        //Now destroy them
        foreach (GameObject child in allChildren)
        {
            DestroyImmediate(child.gameObject);
        }

        Debug.Log(transform.childCount);
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you - this works, but I am still a bit confused as to why my approaches didn't work. I thought it may be because of an indexing issue, but if I use `transform.GetChild(0)` instead of `transform.GetChild(i)` in my second attempt I would've thought it'd get around the issue (alas, it does not).

Comment: It does not because if you destroy the object while still looking for it, it changes position in the hierarchy. So your next loop might have a null object in it, skip some objects or even have a wrong object in the next loop. That's why you get all the objects first then destroy them. At this time, it doesn't matter if they change position in the hierarchy or not.

Comment: I suppose it's better to not think too deeply about the indexing internals of this sort of thing if I don't have to.

Comment: Yup and it's complicated to understand since we don't have the source code. If it is open source then would dig into it right away and see what exactly is going on

Comment: I would not recommend solving this problem this way as it requires twice the number of iterations and an increased memory footprint while neither of these things are necessary

Comment: @star4z - Can you provide an example, then? I would love to understand a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 35):

The other solutions here seem over-engineered. I wanted something with a smaller code footprint. This destroys the immediate children of an object, and all of their descendents.

```
while (transform.childCount > 0) {
    DestroyImmediate(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
}
```

Comment: Brutal and simple. I love it.

Comment: I do think this approach is more elegant, but doing the copy-array-then-delete is useful for times when you want to delete only a subset of the elements. So I was tempted to mark this as correct, but the other way is more flexible.

Comment: Sure, and I didn't answer this 3 years later to be marked the correct answer, but to be clear your question does specifically ask how to reduce the children to zero, not how to filter.

Comment: Your choice of words might suggest that DestroyImmediate is named like this because it destroyes the "immediate" children. It might create confusion for newbies. Please see the appropriate page: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html

Answer (score 6):

Are all the children direct childrens of your parent object?

I believe the foreach(Transform child in transform) will only loop through the children that are in the first level after the parent. So if there are objects that are childrens of a child of a parent they wont be looped. Parent -> Child1 -> Child2 (child of Child1). Hope its undestandable what i mean.

To also get the childrens in second level and forth i would use:

```
Transform[] allChildren = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
```

And then loop through this list to destroy them ([As pointed out by Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46359133/4298200)):

> The problem is that you are trying to remove the Object in the for loop while accessing them.

Comment: *"So if there are objects that are childrens of a child of a parent they wont be looped. Parent -> Child1 -> Child2 (child of Child1). Hope its undestandable what i mean"*. **1.** True but **not** the problem. If you destroy the first level children, it should destroy other children under that child too automatically. **2.** As for using `GetComponentsInChildren`, that **won't** find disabled GameObject. **3.** `GetComponentsInChildren` will also return the parent object. That's tricky but this means that OP will end up destroying the parent object too.

Comment: 1. Dont know why i didnt think about that... where else should thos childrens go :D

2. Wasnt thinking about that either. However 

`GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(includeInactive: true);`

should do the trick right?

3. Well..... you know my problem already :D

Comment: 2.Yes, that should do it. +1 but it some part of this is still wrong + but problem #3 which op can fix by comparing the object with the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Destroy` instead of `DestroyImmidiate`. Unless you have some reason for using the latter. The reason you can't loop through the children is because `DestroyImmidiate` deletes them ASAP while `Destroy` waits until the end of the frame. ASAP will happen sometime in the middle of your loop so your indexes get all messed up.
If you do actually need to destroy them before the end of the frame, try this:

```cs
while (transform.childCount > 0) 
{
    DestroyImmediate(transform.GetChild(0).gameObject);
}
```